# How to specify how the bibliography looks like?

Tags: bibliographies

I am working on a file with many references. The desired output looks like this:

> Jackson, A. (2007). New approaches to drug therapy. *Psychology
>   Today and Tomorrow*, *27*(1), 54-59.

While the current output looks like this:

> Jackson, A. (2007). New approaches to drug therapy. In: *Psychology Today and Tomorrow*, 27.1, pp. 54-59.

Any idea how to specify the desired output to LaTeX?

Comment: Please show us, what you've got so far: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please state whether you use BibTeX or `biblatex`/`biber`.

Comment: I am using biblatex/biber.

Comment: Purely from the subject matter and the example output I guess you want to try `biblatex-apa`'s `style=apa`. But I'm guessing here.

Comment: If my answer below helped you, you may want to consider [up-voting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (once you have enough reputation) and [accepting](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) it. Feedback as to whether or not an answer worked for you is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The desired output looks very much like APA style for an `@article`. The subject matter makes that not less likely.

For `biblatex` (which you use according to your comments) APA style is implemented by `biblatex-apa`'s `style=apa`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{jackson,
  author  = {Jackson, A.},
  title   = {New Approaches to Drug Therapy},
  journal = {Psychology Today and Tomorrow},
  volume  = {27},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {54-59},
  date    = {2007},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,jackson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Jackson, 2007; Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998//References//Jackson, A. (2007). New approaches to drug therapy. Psychology Today and Tomorrow, 27(1), 54–59.//Sigfridsson, E. & Ryde, U. (1998). Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4), 377–395. doi:10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P]

In case you don't need APA style, but only something that looks remotely like APA style, you may want to check out one of the standard styles (`style=authoryear` for example) and modify it according to your needs. See [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864) for a first idea how that could work. Note that `biblatex-apa` is not necessarily a good base to build a style as it has to work really hard to implement all the requirements of the APA and therefore becomes less flexible and customisable.